# Spring Framework JDBC - Database password changes

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jdbc, spring-jdbc

Am running a Spring Application deployed in Apache Tomcat server

With below bean,

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/appln" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="3" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="10" />
    </bean>
```

1. How does this bean works, Will this bean validates the DB credentials for every DB request made from application ?
2. When application is running, and the DataBase password is updated, will this bean fails for any application request or it works since it is already validated

Comment: I need some serious answer to the question

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, when Datasource object as bean(singleton) is created, the database information is validated the first time. After that when you inject your Datasource bean to the transaction manager bean, the database operations will be managed by these beans so ***open session, commit, rollback*** etc. Look the [@Transactional](https://spring.io/guides/gs/managing-transactions/) annotation usage.

For the second one, you could change the bean definition in jar/war/ear, after that restart your application. But you can pass these information in the configuration file like application.properties/datasource.properties that you specified in `applicationContext.xml`. This will simplify your deployments when you change anythings. Without the restart, you cannot do to pass new password for database.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what Semih Okan Pehlivan said,

It is possible to refresh the password for the database if you put the properties in the application.properties, though you would need to add spring-cloud-starter to your dependencies.